# Xcode error on creating sample phonegap app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I got some problem with xCode, so i completely remove it, following this post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4772117?start=0&tstart=0

Then, after a fresh installation of Xcode, i followed the get Started tutorial from Phonegap (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS), but when i run

```
./create ~/Documents/CordovaXY/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.myAppName myAppName
```

I'm having this issue:

```
mv: rename /path/to/my/app/__TESTING__.xcodeproj to /path/to/my/app/myAppName.xcodeproj: No such file or directory
```

What is this about? Can somebody help me? I googled out there but I can't find anything usefull

Comment: "Solved" moving form phonegap-2.4.0 to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder ~/Documents/CordovaXY/HelloWorld doesn't exist.

Comment: unluckely it doesn't exist. If it exist it give a different error, something like "the selected folder is not empty"... Any other ideas?